# Como carregar biblioteca Google MAP Charts

Tags: javascript, maps, google-charts

Ao tentar desenhar um chart do tipo MAP, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: google.visualization.Map is not a function

isso ocorre apenas com esse tipo de chart.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_locations_map);

        function drawChart_locations_map() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ["Cities","Users"],
                    ["Sao Paulo",4460],
                    ["Rio de Janeiro",1935]
                ]);
            var options = {"mapType":"satellite"};
            var chart = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('googlechart_locations_map'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="googlechart_locations_map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `Map()` não pertence a package `corechart`.

**Tente assim:**

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['geochart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_locations_map);

        function drawChart_locations_map() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ["Cities","Users"],
                    ["Sao Paulo",4460],
                    ["Rio de Janeiro",1935]
            ]);

            var options = {
                region: 'BR',
                displayMode: 'markers',
                colorAxis: {colors: ['orange', 'red']}
            };
    
            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('googlechart_locations_map'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="googlechart_locations_map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alterei a package para `geochart` e a função para `GeoChart()`, também adicionei os `options` para que mostre o chart corretamente, seguindo a referência disponível abaixo.

[Referência](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart)